# Can one combine the option: parse-numbers = false with other options of the siuntx package?

Tags: siunitx

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[locale = DE,
            per-mode = fraction,
            quotient-mode = fraction,
            output-product = \cdot]{siunitx}

  \begin{document}

    1.
    \[\frac{\sqrt{\num{2 x 9,81}}}{10}\, \frac{\sqrt{\si{\m}}}{\si{\s}}\text{ and}\]
    2.
    \[\SI[parse-numbers = false]{\sqrt{2 x 9,81} / 10}{\sqrt{\m} \per \s}\]
    is the same, but above looks better.

  \end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

Is there a way to do **2.**, but with the active options `per-mode = fraction, quotient-mode = fraction` and `output-product = \cdot`?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: The options all apply, it's just that as numbers are not parsed things like digit separation do not happen. I'm not sure that is an answer: I have a feeling there is something more to the question!

Comment: From a scientist's point of view: the units are wrong or what is the square root of metre supposed to be?

Comment: Hello @Christian Hupfer! Thank you for your comment. Yes, considered isolated it make no sense. But if you write _sqrt(2 * g * h) = sqrt(2 * 9,81) sqrt(meter) / second * sqrt(h)_, with acceleration due to gravity _g_ and height _h_ (see [Torricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law)). Then it make sense.

Comment: Hello @Joseph Wright! Thank you for your comment. I don't understand your comment, because of my english. What I wish, is to achieve the above result only using `\SI{}{}`, without using `\frac{}{}`, `\si{}` and `\,`. I hope it's now clear.